# How to embed Swagger UI into a webpage?

Tags: swagger-ui

How to embed [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/) into a webpage? Basically I want an API endpoint test environment to embed into my webpage.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you have a plain web page you edit directly, or use a framework like Node.js or React. For simplicity, I'll assume the former.

Download (or clone) the [Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) repository. You'll need the following files from the `dist` folder:

```
swagger-ui.css
swagger-ui-bundle.js
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
```

In the `<head>` section of your web page, add:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swagger-ui.css">
```

Inside the `<body>`, add:

```html
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<script src="swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "https://yourserver.com/path/to/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ]
  })

  window.ui = ui
}
</script>
```

`<div id="swagger-ui"></div>` is the DOM node inside which Swagger UI will be rendered. The `SwaggerUIBundle` constructor initializes Swagger UI. This is where you specify your spec URL and [other parameters](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md).

Comment: Everything works fine now. the url is only works for ..../something.json kind of urls. I have a url gives same swagger response but it is not something like /something.json. it do not ends as .json.

Comment: Hi Helen. What would the answer be in the case of a framework like Node?

Comment: @Peter You can use Swagger UI npm module - either [swagger-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui) (with regular dependencies) or [swagger-ui-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-dist) (dependency-free).

Comment: @Helen I did that for a ruby based slate client , I added these things in the layout.erb but I saw no changes in the rendered website can you help

Comment: @luG_0 please [ask a new question](/questions/ask) and post your code.

Comment: @Helen I did that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562208/integrating-swagger-ui-to-my-a-slate-generated-website

Comment: @Helen, This sounds similar to my question. Could u please help me with this question [Change Swagger index.html logo and header contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704031/change-swagger-index-html-logo-and-header-contents)?

Comment: For anyone wondering, the code above also works fine with a .yaml file in the SwaggerUIBundle 'url' parameter