# How to use the shared layout with the swagger UI (ASP CORE)

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using swagger to make a documentation to my API in ASP.NET Core.

And, I would like to use the shared layout to get the same menu on the top of the documentation page.

I would love to do it without re-creating a custom css file, like the documentation says.

I just hope that someone though the same as me, and I was wondering how.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This solved totally my issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237255/how-to-embed-swagger-ui-to-a-webpage