# Integrating Swagger UI to my a slate generated website

Tags: ruby, swagger-ui, slate

I want to integrate swagger UI into my ruby based slate generated API docs , for that I looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237255/how-to-embed-swagger-ui-into-a-webpage)

and  did the directed changes to the `layout.erb` file adding the required head and body sections but upon building the webpage nothing shows up , these are the modified head and body section.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title><%= current_page.data.title || "API Documentation" %></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swagger-ui.css">

<style>
  <%= Rouge::Themes::MonokaiSublime.render(:scope => '.highlight') %>
</style>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :screen, media: :screen %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :print, media: :print %>
<% if current_page.data.search %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "all" %>
<% else %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag  "all_nosearch" %>
<% end %>
```

```
<body class="<%= page_classes %>" data-languages="<%=h language_tabs.map{ |lang| lang.is_a?(Hash) ? lang.keys.first : lang }.to_json %>">




<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<script src="swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"></script>

<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: "https://qa-refapp.openmrs.org/openmrs/module/webservices/rest/swagger.json",
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ]
    })

    window.ui = ui
   }
</script>
```

I added the complete `layout.erb` file [here](https://pastebin.com/Gaj6a6u6)

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: no error is there just a warning about wdm polling changes

Comment: what is html page source generated for this file?

Comment: I dont have any idea how to check it. do I just need to lookup the developers console??

Comment: Right click in browser window and select something like View page source in the context menu

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XUZthJE4 here is the pasteBin its quite long though!!

Comment: I put this file you show along with swagger ui js\css files, in my site directory and all works. Probably your swagger document is not available because of CORS? try to copy this file "https://qa-refapp.openmrs.org/openmrs/module/webservices/rest/swagger.json" into the folder you put everything and use it from there, just for test.

Comment: and how do I replace the url mentioned above should I replace it with the file directory address?