# Javascript conversion of an OpenAPI V3 json object to Swagger HTML object to update DIV thru jQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, swagger, openapi

In the context of a `npm` / `nodejs` web app, would there be a way to convert an OpenAPI V3 json object into `Swagger` `HTML` to dynamically update a `DIV` thru `jQuery` ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? (E.g. embed Swagger UI into another web page, customize some sections of Swagger UI, etc.)

Comment: Yes, wanna display generated swagger into another web page which contains a section for it...

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to embed Swagger UI into a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46237255/113116) Also check out Swagger UI's npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui

Comment: Indeed. But I'm missing how to convert an OpenAPI json into a Swagger json...

Comment: OpenAPI is the new name for the Swagger YAML/JSON file format, so there's no need to convert anything. Swagger UI can render both `openapi: 3.0.x` files and `swagger: '2.0'` files.

Comment: Got it. Point is: I receive the OpenAPI from an Ajax request, so I have the OpenAPI in a variable. How to pass this object to SwaggerUIBundle ? Is there a way to set the OpenAPI instead of specifying a URL to an OpenAPI file ?

Comment: Found how. By using the spec parameter with SwaggerUIBundle.