# Swagger-UI Custom Logo SpringBoot Jar Application

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have stoplight to create my YAMLs for the API. Swagger-UI is being used to display all the API endpoints to the clients. However I am struck with how to have our logo in the swagger-ui page.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AieFO.png)

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4390

Comment: @Helen - Thanks! I have been to this post before. However I don't understand where to add these CSS changes as my application is referring to Swagger-UI somewhere I couldnt track. Do I need to add something my application that I am currently missing.

Comment: Does your framework/library (Springfox / springdoc-openapi?) support using external Swagger UI assets instead of bundled ones? If yes, you can download the latest [`dist` assets](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist), make the changes, and configure your app to serve the updated assets.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a custom web page with your logo/branding and [embed Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46237255/113116) into it.